# Boost in Qt: Installation and Symbol(s) not found for architectures x86_64

Tags: qt, boost

I am back to Qt and C++ programming after a year break. I am trying to install boost library into Qt on Mac (10.9.4) and I am completely confused. This is what I did:

I installed boost using homebrew.

I see that hpp files are installed here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_2/include/boost
```

and libraries here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_2/lib
```

Now I start a new Qt console project.

the project file:

```
 QT       += core

 QT       -= gui

 TARGET = testQt
 CONFIG   += console
 CONFIG   -= app_bundle

 TEMPLATE = app

 SOURCES += main.cpp

 INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_2
```

And the main file:

```
 #include <QCoreApplication>
 #include <QtCore>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <QDebug>

 #include <boost/regex.hpp>

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   std::string line;
   boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

   while (std::cin)
   {
     std::getline(std::cin, line);
     boost::smatch matches;
     if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
         std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
   }
   return a.exec();
 }
```

Not compiling. Issues:

```
Symbol(s) not found for architectures x86_64
linker command failed with exist code 1
```

Since I am absolutely noob with boost, did I do it right? If yes, why is it not compiling?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with boost too!

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_2/lib -lboost
```

Comment: Reinstalled my boost. It is now in usr/local/. Including this: `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
        -lboost_regex` still produces the architecture error. Having what you said (LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lboost) gives "Library not found for lboost" error.

Comment: Inserting this `CONFIG += c++11` into the project file seems to have solved the problem. Thanks for your help!