# Qt on Mac: boost filesystem library - symbols not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, qt, boost

I am trying to run a Qt project that depends upon boost filesystem library.

```
Qt version: 5.6
Mac OSX 10.12
Xcode version: 8.0
Boost: 1.54
```

When I try to build the project, I get the following error,

```
"typeinfo for std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet in libboost_filesystem-mt.a(utf8_codecvt_facet.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've looked at many threads on stack overflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343335/boost-in-qt-installation-and-symbols-not-found-for-architectures-x86-64), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510535/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-on-mac-when-using-qtopencvffmpeg), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067538/adding-opencv-library-to-qt-creator-and-getting-error-linker-command-failed-wit)), but none of them seem to solve my issue.

My .pro file has the following statements

```
macx:INCLUDEPATH += ../../boost_1_54_0
macx:LIBPATH += ../../boost_1_54_0
macx:LIBS += -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt -larchive -lz
```

[I have static files of boost-filesystem, boost-system, lib archive, libz in the build directory]

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: have you set `LIBPATH` to the directory where your boost libraries are?

Comment: @Hayt yes, I have specified the LIBPATH also

Comment: you should add this to the question then as it is a relevant information for others.

Comment: You said you have the libraries in the build directory? `../../boost_1_54_0` would then not be the directory where the libraries are if I guess correctly.

Comment: I only have the static libraries (libboost_filesystem-mt.a, etc.) in the build directory

Comment: how about setting `LIBPATH` to the build directory then?

Comment: I just tried this, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're building with a mix of `libc++` and `libstdc++`. At a *guess* you need to compile your product with the flag `-stdlib=stdc++`.

> Although I would advise changing your entire compile path to just use the default stdlib (`libc++`), to avoid just this situation

`libstdc++` has the following:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib | c++filt | grep 'std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>' | grep typeinfo
0000000000051710 S typeinfo for std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>
000000000004b760 S typeinfo name for std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>
```

while `libc++` has the following:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libc++.dylib | c++filt | grep '::codecvt<wchar_t' | grep typeinfo
0000000000057ff0 S typeinfo for std::__1::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>
0000000000052070 S typeinfo name for std::__1::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>
```

Note the intervening `::__1::` which is designed to prevent `libc++` and `libstdc++` interactions from breaking your app silently.

Comment: Hi, this worked I think, I'm no longer getting that error. Now I'm getting "Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?" But this seems to be a different issue.